# In Inno Setup: How do you use/know the values for CurPageIDs for custom pages?

Tags: inno-setup

Lets say we set up a page using the CreateInputQueryPage function and we use the NextButtonClick event to control actions taken on that page. How do we refer to the correct CurPageID within that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First initialize your page as a global:

```
...
[code]
var
  UserPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
...
```

Then refer to that page variable (for example within the NextButtonClick event handler) like so:

```
UserPage.ID
```

See the example file CodeDlg.iss for an a complete example with the variable use in evidence.